# AWS Credentials Exception in PHP Laravel application (Ubuntu)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to connect to AWS from Laravel but getting below error

```
   local.ERROR: Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error re$
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www. (truncated...)
) in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvid$
Stack trace:
```

I have provided the correct credentials. Still getting this error. Code works fine on windows. But does not work when I migrated it to ubuntu.

Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: Do you have the specific error? Are you using IAM user or IAM role for credentials? Can you show your code too?

Comment: I have provided the correct credentials. Still getting this error. Code works fine on windows. But does not work when I migrated it to ubuntu.

Comment: Please provide your code sample and the full exception :)